# Grails - populating 2nd and 3rd dropdowns from the 1st one

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I had used before in my application to dynamically populate a second drop down box based on the value selected from the first one (using jQuery, remoteFunction call).

I am not sure how to populate two drop downs (2nd and 3rd one) based on the value selected from the 1st drop down.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: On change of first dropdown, make an ajax call to get the list of items for the second and repopulate it. On change of second dropdown, make an ajax call to get the list of items for the third and repopulate it.

Comment: @JamesKleeh, I need help with the server side. The second and third items are dependent on the first item. I have to populate the second and third dropdowns at the same time while selecting a value from the first item. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, can't you include both of the drop-down's values in the model you would have got from `remoteFunction` call. eg: `model: [dropDown1: dropDown1elements, dropDown2: dropDown2elements]`